# Параметры для пароля пользователя

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем привет!

Есть ли в "БД Oracle" какие-либо ограничения относительно паролей пользователей? На просторах интернета вскользь встречал высказывания о том, что пароль должен начинаться обязательно не с цифры. Возможности проверить непосредственно на базе сейчас нет. В идеале необходима выписка из какого либо источника с параметрами, либо опровержение.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**Правила пароля:**

Единый набор правил паролей применяется ко всем компаниям и пользователям. 
Правила паролей устанавливаются в соответствии со стандартами безопасности Oracle для интернет-приложений.
Общие правила Пароль
Ниже приведены общие правила для паролей:
Пароль должен содержать не менее восьми символов.
Пароль должен содержать по крайней мере один символ нижнего регистра.
Пароль должен содержать по крайней мере один символ верхнего регистра.
Пароль должен иметь как минимум один цифровой символ.
Пароль может содержать один или несколько специальных символов.

**Только специальные символы, которые принимаются, являются**:

- Знак минус (-)
- Нижнее подчеркивание (_)
- Двоеточие (:)
- Одинарные кавычки ( ')
- Звездочкой (*)
- Восклицательный знак (!)
- символ фунта (£)
- Знак доллара ($)
- В знак (@)
- Период (.)
- Запятая (,)
- Слэш (/)
- Слэш ()

Пароль не должен содержать слово в стандартном словаре.
Истечении срока действия пароля Правила
По истечении срока действия пароля пользователя, пользователь не может получить доступ к Oracle Social CRM-приложений.

**Ниже приведены правила истечения срока действия пароля:**

Пользователь должен изменить пароль, по крайней мере один раз каждые 60 дней.
Если пользователь не изменяет пароль до истечения времени, пароля истекает, и пользователь должен изменить пароль при следующем входе в систему для приложений Oracle Social CRM.

**Уникальность пароля**

Когда пользователь изменяет пароль, новый пароль должен отличаться от старого пароля. Если пользователь вводит новый пароль, который так же, как старый пароль, пользователь не может изменить пароль, и получает сообщение об ошибке, указывающее, что новый пароль должен отличаться от старого пароля.

[Источникк](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12547_01/books/SalesComV2.0/index.htm?toc.htm?AboutPasswordRuleshelp.html)

Comment: Эти правила как-то встроены в систему или же это просто рекомендации? Т.е. если я эти параметры не учту, то должна отобразиться ошибка?

Comment: @ИльяСтариков Не знаю, может есть какая то специальная настройка, но мой oracle 11g никаких ошибок не выдает даже если сделать пароль из одной буквы

Answer (score 0):

Упрощённо, примерно так:

1) Создать функцию, которая будет проверять сложность пароля.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_verify_function 
  (username varchar2, 
   password varchar2, 
   old_password varchar2) 
RETURN boolean IS
BEGIN
   ...
END;
```

2) Создать профиль и указать в нём эту функцию. Обратите внимание - другие параметры проверки пароля: время жизни, количество попыток, возможность повторно использовать прошлые пароли - всё это можно задать вне функции верификации пароля.

```
CREATE PROFILE my_profile LIMIT
  FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3
  PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 30
  PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME 30
  PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX 10
  PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION my_verify_function
  PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 1/24
  PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 10;
```

3) Назначить профиль пользователю.

```
ALTER USER kot_obormot PROFILE my_profile;
```

За подробностями - к документации.